# type error: server render is no a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs

i am running the server in nodejs but when i try to access it through reactjs i am getting an error as  TypeError: (0 , _serverRender2.default) is not a function. what should i do??

```
import config from './config';
import apiRouter from './api';
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import sassMiddleware from 'node-sass-middleware';
import serverRender from './serverRender';

const server=express();
server.set('view engine','ejs');

server.use(sassMiddleware({
  src:path.join(__dirname,'sass'),
  dest:path.join(__dirname,'public')
}));

server.get('/',(req,res)=> {
  serverRender()
  .then(content => {
    res.render('index', {
      content
    });
  })
  .catch(console.error);
});

server.use(express.static('public'));

server.use('/api', apiRouter);

server.listen(config.port,  () => {
  console.info('express listening on port ', config.port);
});
```

this is my serverRender file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import App from './src/components/App';
import axios from 'axios';
//import config from './config';

const serverRender = () =>{

axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/contests')
  .then(resp=>{
return ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App initialContests = {resp.data.contests}/>);
   // console.log(resp.data);
  });  
}
export default serverRender;
```

Comment: what is in `serverRender` file?

Comment: share `serverRender.js` file code

Comment: If you launch a node terminal in your project folder, and try to import `serverRender` from it's file, what do you get?

Comment: `serverRender` doesn't return `promise` .

Comment: in node terminal i am getting json data, but when i try it in the browser  using reactjs it displays as type error in node terminal and also in reactjs terminal

Comment: that `import` statement... are you using Babel or smth similar? (`import` is not implemented yet in NodeJs)

Answer (score 1):

`serverRender()` doesn't return `Promise`. You can try to the callback based approach.

```
const serverRender = (callback) =>{
   axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/contests')
     .then(resp=>{
        callback(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App initialContests = {resp.data.contests}/>));
     });  
 }
```

**serverRender.js**

```
server.get('/',(req,res)=> {
   serverRender(content => {
      res.render('index', {
        content
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: which `view engine` you are using in `node.js` ? What is `index` ?

Comment: index.ejs is a file which i am using for front end purpose that is where rendering takes place

Answer (score 0):

You should check the code you wrote in **serverRender.js**

The error you see tells you that you don't *export* any modules from **serverRender.js** as *default*

Comment: i am exporting it from serverRender